# In which manga does everyone around the world become 2 cm tall?

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character's sister writes a novel because she received some kind of message telling her what is going to happen in two years; she had to let the world know, but in an indirect way.

Everyone becomes ~2 cm tall. In return for their height loss, everyone gained an ability. The main character had the title "Prince" and a barrier  ability. That'ss basically all I remember.

I think his sister was also trapped by a person with the ability to enlarge themselves.

Comment: @Paul why the edit that changes Manhua -> Manga? I am not an expert, but from what I understand the two words mean different things.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: looks like they do, I apologise. I think I saw the "manga" tag and assumed that "manhua" in the title was an autocorrect of that. (I can't tell if 3CM Hunter is Chinese or Japanese, so I'm not sure which one is appropriate.) (Also I know very little about comics, so for all I know neither or both words would be used in this context.) (In other words, ‍♂️)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is *3CM Hunter*.

> Everyone shrank down to a height of 3cm. Now, even cats, spiders,
> ants, vacuum cleaners, etc. are life-threatening calamities. The only
> thing left to trust is the respectively given skills to each
> individual person.

[image]

The main character's sister predicts the events that happen two years later.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Haha, no wonder I couldn't find it through googling. Thanks XD